# Difference between compile and runtime configurations in Gradle

Tags: configuration, dependencies, gradle

My question is a little bit common, but it is linked with Gradle too.

**Why we need compile and runtime configuration?**

When I compile something I need artifacts to convert my java classes in bytecode so I need compile configuration, but why is needed runtime configuration do I need something else to run my application in JVM?

Sorry if it sounds stupid, but I don't understand.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

In the most common case, the artifacts needed at compile time are a subset of those needed at runtime. For example, let's say that a program called `app` uses library `foo`, and library `foo` *internally* uses library `bar`. Then only `foo` is needed to compile `app`, but both `foo` and `bar` are needed to run it. This is why by default, everything that you put on Gradle's `compile` configuration is also visible on its `runtime` configuration, but the opposite isn't true.

Comment: Shame this isn't mentioned explicitly in http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html. They use both compile and runtime without stating explicitly their meaning...

Comment: @silasdavis In the documentation explains the difference: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#configurations in 8.3. Dependency configurations

Comment: @angelcervera Ah so it does, 8. Dependency Management Basics, and 51. Dependency Management. I can see why they have two sections, but perhaps it would be nice if the latter referenced the former. I think I landed on 51 and expected it to give a full account.

Comment: @silasdavis True. The same for other sections in the documentation. I must take same free time to read all documentation from A to Z.

Comment: Note that `compile` and `runtime` is dependency configurations of `java` plugin. You can read more about this here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#tab:configurations

Comment: @Peter Niederwieser If the compile task shows the same dependencies as runtime, in what scenario would you use runtime as opposed to compile?

Comment: @rj2700 One could conceivably _compile_ against a set of interfaces and inject different implementations into different artifacts for _runtime_. Java security providers may be one example, Kotlin multi-platform projects another. That said, I haven't come across a use case myself.

Answer (score 20):

Updating the answer as per the latest gradle versions.

From gradle's official documentation at below link:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html

> ***Deprecations***
>
> **Dependencies should no longer be declared using the compile and runtime configurations The usage of the compile and runtime
> configurations in the Java ecosystem plugins has been discouraged
> since Gradle 3.4.**
>
> **The implementation, api, compileOnly and runtimeOnly configurations should be used to declare dependencies and the compileClasspath and
> runtimeClasspath configurations to resolve dependencies.**

More so, the compile dependency configuration has been removed in the recently released Gradle 7.0 version.

If you try to use compile in your Gradle 3.4+ project you’ll get a warning like this:

> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
> incompatible with Gradle 7.0. Use ‘–warning-mode all’ to show the
> individual deprecation warnings.

You should always use implementation rather than compile for dependencies, and use runtimeOnly instead of runtime.

**What is an implementation dependency?**

When you’re building and running a Java project there are two classpaths involved:

**Compile classpath** – Those dependencies which are required for the JDK to be able to compile Java code into .class files.

**Runtime classpath** – Those dependencies which are required to actually run the compiled Java code.

When we’re configuring Gradle dependencies all we’re really doing is configuring which dependencies should appear on which classpath. Given there are only two classpaths, it makes sense that we have three options to declare our dependencies.

1. **compileOnly** – put the dependency on the compile classpath only.
2. **runtimeOnly** – put the dependency on the runtime classpath only.
3. **implementation** – put the dependency on both classpaths.

> **Use the implementation dependency configuration if you need the dependency to be on both the compile and runtime classpaths. If not,
> consider compileOnly or runtimeOnly.**

Comment: Good answer if i wanted only definitions. :D