# Practical difference between Compile and Runtime configurations in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

To start with, I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700939/difference-between-compile-and-runtime-configurations-in-gradle) already so please do not mark as duplicate. Also I tagged `scala` despite this question is really about SBT only, but I think there's greater chance to get answers then.

As is explained there to compile my project SBT only needs part of libs, it does not need libs internally referenced inside libs I use in my code. And to run my code it really needs all the libs, all transitive dependencies.
Theoretically this is clear.

I would like to understand this more practically. For example, if I have a clean empty Scala project do these two configs, `Compile` and `Runtime` differ?
What are real-life use cases when you need to use the `Runime` config in your `build.sbt` explicitly?