# Android dependency hierarchy

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

In the `app` module I added `baseLayerCore` module as a dependency and both `app` and `baseLayerCore` modules need `core` module as their dependency so I defined `core` in `app` but `baseLayerCore` dose not resolve it and needs to be defined in its own `build.gradle` too.

I believe `baseLayerCore` does not need `core` since it has defined in `app`.

Am I wrong?! Why is this happening?

`app build.gradle:`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700939/difference-between-compile-and-runtime-configurations-in-gradle) link, I finally recognized that this error occurs on compile time not run time so I should use `compileOnly` dependancy for `baseLayerCore` and `implementation` for `app` module.These way I can compile the project to see the result but there is no need to have the dependency on run time.