# IntelliJ: Cannot resolve symbol 'GenericGenerator'

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, gradle

According to this article https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-and-uuid-identifiers/
I wanted to generate with hibernate UUID to my class. IntelliJ says that 'Cannot resolve 'GenericGenerator' '. It doesnt recognize the GenericGenerator import neither.

Entity.java:

```java
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Entity {
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "CHAR(32)")
    @Id
    protected String id;

    public BaseEntity() {
    }
}
```

I have these dependencies in my build.gradle:

```
compile group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'javax.persistence-api', version: '2.2'
runtime group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.4.9.Final'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `@GenericGenerator` annotation is part of `hibernate-core`, I'd check if the dependency has been registered correctly in the IntelliJ module. Sometimes it helps to re-import the project via `build.gradle`. Also I'd change the [dependency type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700939/difference-between-compile-and-runtime-configurations-in-gradle) from `runtime` to `compile` as the dependency is needed at compile time as well.

```
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.4.9.Final'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the scope to "compile" for 'org.hibernate' dependency:

```
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.4.9.Final'
```

More info about Gradle scopes: [Difference between compile and runtime configurations in Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700939/difference-between-compile-and-runtime-configurations-in-gradle)