# Could not find method compile() for arguments in java

Tags: java, gradle

[image]can anybody help me solve this problem

> Could not find method compile() for arguments [project ':moqui-util'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.[image]

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3111149)

Comment: some people do not like to read code from black background; most cannot copy code from an image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between implementation, api and compile in Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-api-and-compile-in-gradle)

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Gradle version 7.0+, then compile dependency configuration is removed from that. You might need to look for **implementation** dependency configuration in place of compile.

PS: Do not forget to rebuild your gradle file.

More info can be found here at my another answer for this deprecation.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67695126/8148637

Comment: I dont exactly understand your answer could you please tell me what should I do in code ?

Comment: In dependencies {} closure in your build file, you have some compile dependencies like 'javax.cache','javax.servlet' . Replace them from being compile dependencies to be implementation dependencies. In other words, replace the word compile at the starting of all such dependencies with the word 'implementation'

Comment: You need to reload your gradle build file after the change. It will appear at the right top of your editor when you make the change.

Comment: @KnockingHeads How to resolve this issue in case of plugins {} closure dependency and not the dependencies {} closure?

Comment: TL;DR compile is deprecated, use implementation instead.

Answer (score 6):

It looks pretty straightforward, but i didn't see many examples of what needs to be changed. This is what I had to do:

Anything like this, change from

```
compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version: '1.7.25'
```

to

```
implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.25'
```

I also had to change the way `mainClass` is declared

```
mainClassName = 'package.MainClass'
```

to

```
application {
mainClass = 'package.MainClass'
```

}

To get to this, I had to delete the `gradle` files and folder, and do a `gradle init` to recreate the build configs and dependencies.
Use `implementation`, `runtimeOnly`, `compileOnly` etc. as the new equivalents

Comment: TL;DR compile is deprecated, use implementation instead.